# Adding Facebook credentials won't stick

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, user-accounts, facebook

I have been changing devices recently, and I am finding fussing around with a long, unique password too much of a hassle when I am away from my password database. Time to add my Facebook account to StackExchange as an alternative authentication source.

Reproducible Steps:

1. I go to Edit Profile and Settings, and see I have two email addresses and a MyOpenId already registered. Great.
2. I click `Add more logins...`
3. I click `Facebook`
4. StackExchange says:

   > Confirm A New Login
   >   Add a login from
   >
   > MyEMailAddressIs ( NoneOfYourBusiness@example.com)
   >
   > We will automatically link this account with your accounts on other Stack Exchange sites.
5. Sounds perfect. I click `Confirm New Login`
6. StackExchange returns to my profile page.
7. I view my logins again. No change (I was expecting Facebook to appear).
8. Try to login in to StackExchange with Facebook on my phone. It doesn't associate it with my account, and offers to create a new one, which I decline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was you already had a very, very old network account using that email address, and it had an active stackexchange.com profile. Since you're a moderator somewhere, the merge process which would combine the two accounts and add the credential immediately terminates because that's not allowed.

I've killed off that extra profile and merged the two network accounts together, so your Facebook credential can now be used properly with this account.